# Where should print function be used here?

Tags: python

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x>y:
    if x%y==0:
        print(y)
    else:
        z = x%y
        while z>0:
            z = (x//y)%z
else:
    if y%x==0:
        print(x)
    else:
        z1 = y%x
        while z1>0:
            z1 = (y//x)%z1
```

A code for finding GCD. As I am new at programming I don't know where should the print function for else conditions be to print the GCD properly.

Comment: Firstly there is a need to fix your indentations.

Comment: Can you please point it out?

Comment: Looks like you have it.

Comment: Still can't figure out the actual issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i suggest use built in `gcd` function for this aim ! this is more **pythonic** !

```
>>> from fractions import gcd
>>> gcd(a,b)
```

and if you want a algorithm you can use this :

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        (a, b) = (b, a % b)
    return a
```

Comment: My teacher said I can't use the built in function which was the problem to begin with. But, the algorithm helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As following your logic i just modify some code so that it can run properly:

Here is the modified code:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
if x>y:
    if x%y==0:
        print(y)
    else:
        x = x%y
        while x!=0:
            y=x
            x=x%y
        print y
else:
    if y%x==0:
        print(x)
    else:
        y=y%x
        while y!=0:
            x=y
            y=y%x
        print x
```

Hope this will help you to show in front of teacher:)

Comment: No problem.Even i can understand your feeling as i am also student.

Comment: May i know the input you had tested?